# How to multiply a matrix by a scalar value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to multiply an image by a scalar value in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). How do I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just use the `*` operator, as you might expect, e.g.

```
y = x * k;
```

where x is the input image, k is a scalar value, and y is the resulting scaled image.